# Adding elements to a dictionary in a forEach loop javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
let pages = {}
    let commandSections = await fs.readdirSync("./commands")
    
    let pageNum = 1
    await commandSections.forEach(async e => {
      let sectionCommands = await fs.readdirSync(`./commands/${e}`)
      let pageInfo = ''
      await sectionCommands.forEach(async element => {
        let desc = await client.commands.get(element.split(".")[0]).description
        pageInfo += `${element.split(".")[0]} - ${desc}\n`
      })
      pages[pageNum] = {"name": e, "value": pageInfo}
      pageNum++
    })
```

^^ my code is up there, and as you can see there, i define pages as a dictionary. i then proceed to have a few forEach loops (to loop through the commands of a discord bot), which add key/value pairs to the dictionary. the problem is, whenever i try to access the dictionary, it returns as an empty dictionary ({}). when i console.log "pages" inside the forEach loop though, it returns as the proper thing. any ideas?

Comment: Short explanation : `forEach` and `await` doesn't go hand in hand, sure it would fire away the `async` calls but wouldn't wait for each of the promise resolution. Simply use normal for loop `for(let i = 0; i < length; ++i)` instead of `forEach` at both loops. should work. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: [`async/await` with `forEach`](https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all You don't need to use `await` with `fs.readdirSync` becuse this method is not async.

[You can't find docs for this method here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options)

Potentially, the problem here is that `forEach` function doesn't wait for async callbacks.
It just calls callback You pass.
If you need to work with async operations within array iteration You better user [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for_statement) for that. It works perfectly with async code.